# what is the correct name for identifying difference between web and mobile applications?

Tags: google-analytics, e-commerce, terminology

I am not sure how to ask this properly so i need to clarify this with an example.

Assume that you have an e-commerce website with mobile applications, and you want to filter your "foo" entities with a field which is including types like "WEB, APP"

What is the correct naming for this field? 
Platform? 
Channel?
Someting else? 
What is the equivalent term in marketing for this?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases I would use Channel for that. Each channel is linked to a platform as described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multichannel_marketing